# I am trying to click on expand button and then scrape the table

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, html5lib

I am scraping a website table form https://csr.gov.in/companyprofile.php?year=FY+2015-16&CIN=L00000CH1990PLC010573 but I am not getting the exact result I am looking for. I want 11 columns from this link, "company name", "Class", "State", "Company Type", "RoC", "Sub Category", "Listing Status". These are 7 columns and after that you can see an expand button " CSR Details of FY 2017-18" when you will click on that button you will get 4 more columns "Average Net Profit", "CSR Prescribed Expenditure", "CSR Spent", "Local Area Spent". I want all these columns in csv file. I wrote a code and it is not working properly. I am attaching an Image of result for refference. and here is my code. please help to get these data.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
import csv

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url_file = "csrdata.txt"

with open(url_file, "r") as url:
    url_pages = url.read()
# we need to split each urls into lists to make it iterable
pages = url_pages.split("\n") # Split by lines using \n
data = []

# now we run a for loop to visit the urls one by one
for single_page in pages:
    driver.get(single_page)
    r = requests.get(single_page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("CSR Details of FY 2017-18").click()
    table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'colfy4')]")
    about = table.__getitem__(0).text
    x = about.split('\n')

    print(x)

    data.append(x)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(df)

    # write to csv
    df.to_csv('csr.csv')
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to use selenium since all the informations are inside the html code. Also you can use pandas inbuild function `pd_read_html()` to directly transform the html-table into a dataframe.

```
data = []
for single_page in pages:
    r = requests.get(single_page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

    table = soup.find_all('table')               #finds all tables
    table_top = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]      #the top table

    try:                                         #try to get the other table if exists
        table_extra = pd.read_html(str(table))[7]
    except:
        table_extra = pd.DataFrame()            
    
    result = pd.concat([table_top, table_extra])
    data.append(result)

pd.concat(data).to_csv('test.csv')
```

output:

```
                            0                          1
0                       Class                     Public
1                       State                 Chandigarh
2                Company Type           Other than Govt.
3                         RoC             RoC-Chandigarh
4                Sub Category  Company limited by shares
5              Listing Status                     Listed
0          Average Net Profit                          0
1  CSR Prescribed Expenditure                          0
2                   CSR Spent                          0
3            Local Area Spent                          0
```

Comment: getting error on 5th link, because there is no table in " CSR Details of FY 2017-18" """"""'table_extra = pd.read_html(str(table))[7]  # the table from "CSR Details of FY 2017-18"
IndexError: list index out of range""""""'

Comment: how can I set an exception that if there is no table found in " CSR Details of FY 2017-18" like this link "https://csr.gov.in/companyprofile.php?year=FY+2017-18&CIN=L01110GJ1991PLC015846". please help

Comment: You can use "try" and "except". I edited my post above.

Comment: I am very thankfull to you for the help, I have one more issue. code is running very well and output is printing. but I am not getting the outout csv file. I tried too much but not getting output csv file in destination folder.

Comment: Do you want to save the DataFrame for each page in an unique csv-file?

Comment: I need all page results in single csv file.

Comment: In this case you can save all the DataFrame of each page into a list and then concat this list to csv. I edited my post above. In this line: pd.concat(data).to_csv('test.csv') you can change the path where i shall be saved (change 'test.csv' to the path you want).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Can you please help suggest me a better plateform to learn web scraping using Python? Once aagain thank you for the help.

Comment: Happy to help. Hard to suggest something, because I don’t know how best you learn, but I really like the YouTube channel “TechWithTim”. He has a video of web scraping with python and a lot of other python tutorials. Maybe this helps you, too.